# Leekchan Accounting conflicting with ShopSpring Decimal

Tags: go

I'm trying out the samples at https://github.com/leekchan/accounting

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
    "github.com/leekchan/accounting"
)

func main() {
    ac := accounting.Accounting{Symbol: "$", Precision: 2}
    fmt.Println(ac.FormatMoney(123456789.213123))
}
```

and using them exactly as showing on Github I'm getting the following error:

> Failed parsing input: package "github.com/shopspring/decimal" is imported from multiple locations: "/users/dev/go/src/github.com/shopspring/decimal" and "/users/dev/go/src/github.com/leekchan/accounting/vendor/github.com/shopspring/decimal"

I can't leave out:

```
github.com/shopspring/decimal
```

or I'll get another error. I tried:

```
"dec" github.com/shopspring/decimal
```

but that doesn't change anything. Shouldn't it?

Weird thing is I can't find any details about this anywhere. Am I really the only person getting this, or am I missing something completely obvious?

Answer (score 2):

This is because they have a checked in vendor directory that contains github.com/shopspring/decimal which it appears you already have on your path. You are best having a single vendor directory inside your project that contains both github.com/shopspring/decimal and github.com/leekchan/accounting so that you directory structure will look like:

```
- main.go
| - vendor
  | - github.com/leekchan/accounting
  | - github.com/shopspring/decimal
```

Comment: so I need to remove shopspring/decimal from leekchan/accounting?

Comment: Yeah, when you copy leekchan into you vendor directory flatten out the nested vendor directory by putting it's contents into your packages vendor directory